# trouble with document.getElementById().onclick

Tags: window.open

I need to create a T&C's splash page whereby the user ticks the box and then the submit button enables and forwards them onto the correct page.

Currently I cannot figure out why the following code makes the terms checkbox the active link - clicking on it to check the box loads the page from window.open

If I comment out the two window.open lines it all works as intended but without link function.  Clearly I am trying to create a page that works on all mobile and desktop clients otherwise I would use an inline onclick in the button html.

Thanks for your help...

```js
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateBox(element) {

      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("submit").value = "Press here to go online";
  document.getElementById("submit").onclick= window.open('<?php print $grant_url ?>');
  document.getElementById("submit").ontouchstart= window.open('<?php print $grant_url ?>');
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("submit").value = "Please agree to T&C's";
      }

  }; 
</script>
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateBox(this)" autofocus />
      I Agree to the Terms & Conditions <br>
  
      <input class="button" name="submit" value="Please agree to T&C's" id="submit" title="Continue to the Internet" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (wrapping the `window.open` calls in anonymous functions)

```
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateBox(element) {

      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("submit").value = "Press here to go online";
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick= function() { window.open('<?php print $grant_url ?>'); }
        document.getElementById("submit").ontouchstart= function() { window.open('<?php print $grant_url ?>'); }
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submit").value = "Please agree to T&C's";
      }

  }; 
</script>
```

Comment: That did the job nicely.  Thanks!